# Can initramfs be paged out to swap disk?

Tags: linux, memory, swap, initramfs

I am using `initramfs` to boot Centos via PXE. The `initramfs` used memory is listed within the "cached" value in `/proc/meminfo` or via `free`.

Since I need to calculate performance data, I need to know whether the memory used by the `initramfs` is reclaimable (i.e. can be swapped out to disk) or not. Typically only a very small part of the `/` filesystem tree is actually in use, so a majority of the `initramfs` could be swapped out.

Reading on this I got conflicting information. Some sources claimed that `initramfs` behaves like `initrd` and is based on `ramfs`, which means claimed memory cannot be paged out to swap. Other sources claim that `initramfs` is essentially `tmpfs` which in turn would imply that it can be paged out to swap.

Which is true? Can the unused parts of the `initramfs` filesystem be paged out to swap space?

Comment: I guess that's easy to find out with a VM with little memory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT: Answer updated/corrected.**

Although the [kernel documentation about this topic](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) says that "Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled) [...]",
it is in reality still a ramfs, as a short look in the code shows (`rootfs` 
is not mentioned in [`mm/shmem.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/shmem.c)).

Some patches (see e.g. [here](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=107008367512776&w=4) and [here](http://lkml.org/lkml/2006/7/30/120)) were sent to the [Linux kernel mailing list (lkml)](http://lkml.org/) to change this. But they were not accepted. One reason was, that you normally do not have enabled swap during the initramfs phase or in embedded systems.

The initramfs image is extracted to the rootfs. Before user space (usually `switch_root` called from `/init`) switches to the new root, it deletes the content of the rootfs such that only the minimal memory amount of an empty ramfs is remains. So after this, you can basically ignore its memory usage and the question if it can be swapped out, is nearly irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I should clarify: i do not perform `switch_root`, the initramfs is a 2GB cpio archive of a full CentOS Installation booted via PXE, it stays as rootfs. Therefore i would like to know whether a local swap device could free some of the unused 2GB.

Comment: Also, according to http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1463249: 

"Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled)" but it has always been a lie, until now.

So i am not sure whether rootfs is actually a tmpfs or still ramfs, how to check?

Comment: @dfens123, instead of having the client download the whole system into a massive rootfs, why don't you just mount root over NFS?

Comment: @dfens123 I corrected my answer.

Comment: @jofel Thanks for the answer, that clears it up for me. Unfortunately to me it kind of is "relevant" :-)

Comment: @psusi: i want non-persistance with rw on / and a single image for all nodes. Also less reliability on NFS.

Comment: i suppose i could extract the cpio archive into an actual tmpfs and switch_root from the ramfs/rootfs

Comment: @jofel, comment on the LKLM list: initramfs apparently should have been tmpfs for a long time IMHO. Seems to me a kern dev failure or simply lazyness (its a 2006 suggestion). "i personally don't see a use case" by that kern dev is just stupid. I suppose i will apply and patch the kernel myself, should be trivial.

Comment: The *`initramfs` is* the *`rootfs`* - it's not extracted, its *`image`* is.

Comment: @mikeserv I clarified my answer. Actually, as there is no *initramfs file system* (there is only the initramfs image), *`initramfs`* and *`initramfs image`* are synonyms. The initramfs image is really extracted to rootfs, see the [corresponding function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/initramfs.c#L424).

Comment: After a fashion - but `initramfs` is `rootfs` - which is just a part of `vfs` - the kernel's page cache - mounted as `/ root.` It is a filesystem - the most basic one there is - but it serves many purposes. In any case, `cpio` is *not* a filesystem - it is an archive format. Without `initramfs` being a filesystem, how could you mount the `cpio` image?

Comment: @mikeserv AFAIK, the kernel mounts a ramfs into which it extracts the cpio image (as I wrote in my answer). There is no possibility to mount directly an initramfs/cpio image (it is e.g. not listed in `/proc/filesystems`). The initramfs code offers no VFS routines like the other (real) filesystem modules and is therefore no mountable filesystem.

Comment: It must be *real* - it's mounted. But you're right it's practically useless aside from its one purpose. Anyway, it is a `ramfs` - the `initramfs` - which is what you wrote and is correct. But it is a filesystem - it has files that are read and executed at boot. How could it be otherwise? If you're running Linux right now it's mounted right now, and your root device is mounted over it.

Comment: Note that part-way through this discussion, patches were merged to change the behaviour. Now it is possible to use tmpfs as rootfs in some scenarios. They updated the documentation... but managed to document the wrong behaviour again, oops! I have added an updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `rootfs` file data can only be paged out if it is implemented with `tmpfs`, not `ramfs`.

Since Linux v3.12, `tmpfs` is used in some cases.  If I read the code correctly, this *only* happens if you do not pass a `root=` option.  You can force ramfs to be used by passing `rootfstype=ramfs`, but you cannot force tmpfs by passing `rootfstype=tmpfs.

If you have the `stat` command, `stat -f .` will confirm whether you are on a `ramfs` equivalent, or a `tmpfs` equivalent, or a different type of filesystem altogether.

---

This was implemented in:

> [6e19eded3684 "initmpfs: use initramfs if rootfstype= or root= specified "](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/6e19eded3684dc184181093af3bff2ff440f5b53)
>
> Command line option rootfstype=ramfs to obtain old initramfs behavior, **and use ramfs instead of tmpfs for stub when root= defined** (for cosmetic reasons).

It is a bit confusing, for two reasons.  Firstly, it effectively overrides the logic in the commit that comes immediately before it:

> [16203a7a942 "initmpfs: make rootfs use tmpfs when CONFIG_TMPFS enabled"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/16203a7a9422315bc929461503e3a046459ea5ff)
>
> Conditionally call the appropriate fs_init function and fill_super
>   functions.

Secondly, the test for `root=` does not seem to be mentioned in the documentation, even in v4.17:

> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt
>
> If CONFIG_TMPFS is enabled, rootfs will use tmpfs instead of ramfs by
>   default.  To force ramfs, add "rootfstype=ramfs" to the kernel command
>   line.