# Does Linux still use rootfs?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, root-filesystem

In the kernel documentation file "[ramfs, rootfs, and initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)" it says

> Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled), which is
>   always present in 2.6 systems.

I have not seen `rootfs` in `/proc/mounts` on my desktop installations of Linux, but I do see it on my Android phone. Both run Linux 3. Is `rootfs` still necessary? What is it, too?

Comment: Read on and you will find notes on `initramfs`. In most PC distros, people still use `initramfs` wth some old `initrd` filename at boot.

Answer (score 1):

rootfs doesn't show in /proc/mounts - so does this mean the doc out of date?  No.  See [Why is there no rootfs file system present on my system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system/455136#455136)

> As of Linux v4.17, this kernel documentation is still up to date. 
>   rootfs is always present; it cannot be unmounted.  But a lot of the
>   time you cannot see it in /proc/mounts.
>
> You can see rootfs if you boot into an initramfs shell.  If your
>   initramfs is `dracut`, as in Fedora Linux, you can do this by adding
>   the option `rd.break` to the kernel command line.  (E.g. inside the
>   GRUB boot loader):
>
> ```
> switch_root:/# grep rootfs /proc/mounts
> rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
> ```
>
> When dracut switches the system to the real root filesystem, you can
>   no longer see rootfs in /proc/mounts.  dracut can use either
>   `switch_root` or `systemd` to do this.  Both of these follow the same
>   sequence of operations, as specified in the [linked kernel
>   doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt).
>   The operation which hides rootfs is `chroot`.
>
> ```
> switch_root:/# cd /sysroot
> switch_root:/sysroot# mount --bind /proc proc
> switch_root:/sysroot# grep rootfs proc/mounts
> rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
>
> switch_root:/sysroot# chroot .
> sh-4.4# cat proc/mounts
> /dev/sda3 / ext4 ro,relatime 0 0
> proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
> ```
>
> [...]