# chroot before pivot_root causes busy error

Tags: linux

```
# unshare -m
# mount --bind / /mnt
# cd /mnt
# chroot .
# pivot_root . mnt
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `mnt': Device or resource busy
```

Why does it fail?  I was following the instructions from `man 2 pivot_mount`.

> pivot_root() may or may not change the current  root  and  the  current
>          working  directory  of  any processes or threads which use the old root
>          directory.  The caller of pivot_root() must ensure that processes  with
>          root  or current working directory at the old root operate correctly in
>          either case.  An easy way to ensure this is to change  their  root  and
>          current working directory to new_root before invoking pivot_root().

I don't see how this matches the documented EBUSY error.

> ERRORS
>
> pivot_root() may return (in  errno)  any  of  the  errors  returned  by
>          stat(2).  Additionally, it may return:
>
> **EBUSY**  new_root  or  put_old  are  on the current root filesystem, or a
>                 filesystem is already mounted on put_old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That part of the manpage is misleading.  Generally you want a different ordering, as described in `man 8 pivot_root`.

```
cd new_root             # chdir(new_root);
pivot_root . put_old    # pivot_root(".", put_old);
exec chroot .           # chroot(".");
```

This seems to be yet another subtle detail with `pivot_root`. Although the point of `pivot_root` is to rearrange the mount namespace, the [kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/namespace.c#L3154) seems to say that the root filesystem that it moves is determined by the per-process root, which is what `chroot` sets.

As a result, we hit the error "new_root or put_old are on the current root filesystem".

This subtle detail of `pivot_root` is necessary in order for it to work *at all* on modern Linux. If it was defined to work on the root mount of the mount namespace, it would try to move the special `rootfs` filesystem which you [normally can't see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238705/does-linux-still-use-rootfs/455133).  But [this is not allowed, because rootfs must always be the root mount of the namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455223/pivot-root-from-initramfs-to-new-root-error-invalid-argument).

---

We can confirm `pivot_root` works this way, by continuing the example as follows.

```
# unshare -m
# mount --bind / /mnt
# cd /mnt
# chroot /mnt
# pivot_root . mnt
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `mnt': Device or resource busy

# exit  # leave chroot
# mount --bind . mnt
# cd mnt
# mount --bind /proc proc
# findmnt | grep mnt
└─/mnt                                /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-fedora ext4            rw,relatime,seclabel
  └─/mnt                              /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-fedora ext4            rw,relatime,seclabel
    └─/mnt/proc                       proc                              proc            rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime

# chroot /mnt  # re-enter chroot
# cd /mnt
# pivot_root . mnt  # this one works
# exit  # leave chroot
# findmnt | grep mnt
└─/mnt                                /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-fedora        ext4            rw,relatime,seclabel
  ├─/mnt/mnt                          /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-fedora        ext4            rw,relatime,seclabel
  └─/mnt/proc                         /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-fedora[/proc] ext4            rw,relatime,seclabel
```

The second `pivot_root` call works.  But it didn't have any effect on the root of the mount namespace.  Looking from outside the `chroot`, it swapped `/mnt` and `/mnt/mnt`.