# Why does switch_root delete all the files in the initramfs?

Tags: linux, initramfs, util-linux

> WARNING: switch_root removes recursively all files and directories on the current root filesystem.

-- `man switch_root` from `util-linux`, version `2.32-2.fc28.x86_64`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact behaviour of `switch_root` is explained here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

> When switching another root device, initrd would pivot_root and then
>       umount the ramdisk.  But initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root
>       rootfs, nor unmount it.  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to
>   free up the space (`find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'`) ...

And the reason Linux doesn't support unmounting the initial rootfs:

> Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled), which is
>   always present in 2.6 systems.  You can't unmount rootfs for approximately the
>   same reason you can't kill the init process; rather than having special code
>   to check for and handle an empty list, it's smaller and simpler for the kernel
>   to just make sure certain lists can't become empty.