Weird result mounting a tmpfs as root in the directory tree
Using unshare -Umr I created a new user, mount namespaces where the calling process is moved into. Then via mount -t tmpfs tmpfs / I mounted a new tmpfs instance on the root / of the directory tree within the new mount namespace.
Since the tmpfs is empty I would expect to see an empty list from the command ls -la /, however here is the output:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ unshare -Umr /bin/bash
root@ubuntu:~# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /
root@ubuntu:~# ls -la /
total 5309704
drwxr-xr-x  24 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 22  2023 .
drwxrwxrwt   2 root   root            40 Nov 11 15:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 Jan 25  2023 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 nobody nogroup       4096 Jan 25  2023 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 11  2019 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  17 nobody nogroup       3820 Aug 22 14:22 dev
drwxr-xr-x 105 nobody nogroup       4096 Mar 14  2024 etc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    1688371200 Jan 19  2021 GISO
drwxr-xr-x   3 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 11  2019 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup         34 Jan 25  2023 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-202-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup         34 Jan 25  2023 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-132-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 nobody nogroup       4096 Jan 25  2023 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 Jan 25  2023 lib64
drwx------   2 nobody nogroup      16384 Nov 11  2019 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 Feb 10  2021 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup       4096 Aug  5  2019 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 26  2020 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 123 nobody nogroup          0 Aug 22 12:22 proc
drwx------   4 nobody nogroup       4096 Dec  6  2023 root
drwxr-xr-x  24 nobody nogroup        820 Nov 11 15:20 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup      12288 Jan 25  2023 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 11  2019 snap
drwxr-xr-x   3 nobody nogroup       4096 Jan 24  2020 srv
-rw-------   1 nobody nogroup 3748659200 Nov 11  2019 swap.img
dr-xr-xr-x  13 nobody nogroup          0 Nov 11 15:40 sys
drwxrwxrwt  10 nobody nogroup       4096 Nov 11 15:42 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 nobody nogroup       4096 Aug  5  2019 usr
drwxr-xr-x  13 nobody nogroup       4096 Aug  5  2019 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup         31 Jan 25  2023 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-202-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nobody nogroup         31 Jan 25  2023 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-132-generic
root@ubuntu:~#

as in the filesystem mounted as / before the tmpfs was mounted over.
Why I am getting this result ?

Overmounting the root filesystem can have surprising results.  The short answer is "well don't do that then" :-).
The longer answer is that Linux systems do it every time they start up.  It is technically possible, but you have to tread carefully.
How to explain your results
The path / is a special case.  It resolves to the root directory of the current process.  It does not check if another filesystem has been mounted on top.
Related case: overmounting a non-root directory
Consider resolving a path that does not start with /.  In that case, resolution starts from the current directory of the current process.  It does not check if another filesystem has been mounted on top of the current directory.
# cd /mnt
# touch old-mnt-file
# ls
old-mnt-file

# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt
# ls
old-mnt-file

# touch /mnt/new-mnt-file
# ls /mnt
new-mnt-file


path_resolution(7) — Linux manual page
If the pathname starts with the '/' character, the starting lookup directory is the root directory of the calling process
[...]
If the pathname does not start with the '/' character, the starting lookup directory of the resolution process is the current working directory of the process.

Practical ways to change the root directory
The root directory of the current process can be changed.  This is called "chroot".
The root directory of the current namespace can be replaced.  This is called "pivot_root".
After "pivot_root", it is possible to unmount the previous root filesystem if there are no processes still using it.  This is not possible with "chroot".
If you need to, there is a way to overmount a new root directory for the current process.  It is useful in the "initramfs":
WARNING: "switch_root" will delete all files and directories on the current root filesystem. Do not run the "switch_root" command on your main filesystem.

(If [initramfs] needs to hand
off control it can overmount / with a new root device and exec another init program.  See the switch_root utility, below.)
When switching another root device, [an old-style] initrd would pivot_root and then
umount the ramdisk.  But [nowadays] initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root
rootfs, nor unmount it.  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to
free up the space (find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'), overmount rootfs
with the new root (cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .), attach
stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and exec the new init.
Since this is a remarkably persnickety process (and involves deleting
commands before you can run them), the klibc package introduced a helper
program (utils/run_init.c) to do all this for you.  Most other packages
(such as busybox) have named this command "switch_root".
-- Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.rst

A not-so-practical method
If overmounting a new root filesystem does not actually change /, then is there any way to access the overmounted filesytem?
The special case affects /.  It also affects /., because path resolution can simply strip . path segments.
However, the path .. does check for mounted filesystems.  It seems the same is true for /mnt/...  And even /...
It seems that you can use chroot /.. to switch to the overmounted root filesystem.  I don't remember this being used anywhere.  I recommend using the standard methods from "switch_root" instead.  It will be easier for most people to understand.  Including us - when we inevitably forget this Q&A and have to look everything up again :-).

Ah ok, therefore cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot . is basically the same as the switch_root command in busybox. Btw: when initramfs is gone and the "final/target" root filesystem is mounted on / , is there any evidence of the previously mounted initramfs as / in the output of mount/findmnt command ?

No evidence is left in mount/findmnt: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system/455136#455136

I read the link you referenced. Is rootfs actually a "special type" of RAM-based filesystem (basically a sort of tmpfs or procfs filesystem)?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system/455136#comment1507509_455136

Sorry, regarding your answer: the point is that the bash's child process that runs ls -la / sees mounted on / the root filesystem of the current mount namespace (i.e. the mount namespace the process running ls -la / belongs to). If the above is true, which processes actually see the content of the newly tmpfs filesystem mounted on top of /?

/ is the root directory of the current process.  The root directory of the process is inherited from its parent process, e.g. ls -la inherits the same root directory as bash.  I suppose the namespace root is a bit more obscure subject...

Sorry to be pedantic: in the end, which processes (without doing switch_root) see the content of the tmpfs instance mounted on to /?

No process will see the new tmpfs mounted on /, unless you do the "switch_root" proceedure. Or unless a process re-enters the mount namespace using setns() for some strange reason. Note: I have edited the answer.

Ah ok, you mean whether some process calls setns() after the new tmpfs is mounted over /, it gets it instead of the filesystem previously mounted there.

sorry for typo! I meant to mount /mnt, not / in this example. couldn't easily test as I was responding from Windows.

Ok now it works! It seems the behavior is the same whether I unshare to a new mount namespace using unshare -m /bin/bash. Is that also expected? Thx.

Yes, I think so.

I did an experiment like here. By mistake I had a tmpfs instance mounted on / and it didn't work. The problem was the path referenced in chdir(..) led to the / of the tmps filesystem rather than to the root of the "normal" sda2 ext4 filesystem mounted on / at system startup. Is this an expected result ? Thx.

Huh.  I feel like I've noticed your original question before, but I don't remember encountering your followup:  I was just wrong about "There is no pathname that can access the tmpfs...". /dir/.. accesses the tmpfs just fine, which is entirely consistent with the logic at the start of this answer.

"There is no pathname that can acces the tmpfs..." you meant a tmpfs instance mounted for example on /mnt not on /. The latter is still not accessible via any pathname, I believe.

it turns out, /mnt/.. or even /.. will successfully access a tmpfs which has been mounted on top of /

sorry maybe I misinterpreted your comment. The command ls / actually doesn't shows the content of a tmps filesystem mounted on top of /.

Agreed. ls /mnt/.. or ls /.. did though, when I tried it.  BTW I've enjoyed digging this all up, thanks for all your prompts.  Edited the answer again.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I successfully tested it. Mounting a tmpfs instance on / (mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /) you can get its (empy) content via ls /..
